# How to display an explicit message with Html.LabelFor() as merely the name of the model's property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

With ASP.NET MVC 1.0, we could write something like:

```
<label for = "FirstName">First Name:</label>
```

Which displays "**First Name:**" on screen. Now, with ASP.NET MVC 2.0, we have

```
<% = Html.LabelFor(model => model>FirstName)%>
```

Which displays "**FirstName**" on the screen. It looks to me a little odd to display things like FirstName, LastName, ... (instead of First Name:, Last Name:, ...). **Is there anyway, to get a more explicit text with Html.LabelFor()???**

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your model:

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and you'll need this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Comment: Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute will give you the same result, but with more options...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one as well

```
 @Html.Label("Your Custom Label Text in Here")
```